# Can crakers see javadoc and comments from apk file?

Tags: android, apk, javadoc

I think that .apk does not contain comments. (//commnet or /*comment*/ in .java or .xml)

Can crackers see javadoc from apk file? (/** javadoc */ in .java)

Comment: Whats the point? No they don't.

Comment: I guess the point is that someone might leave sensitive data in the javadoc, which might be a problem. I wouldn't put any sensitive data in the javadoc though...

Comment: @johntheripp3r I want to know they can't (not don't)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments, including javadoc comments, are not included in compiled bytecode.

XML comments are also not included in the Android binary XML format the resource XML files are compiled to.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be..if apk is not protected,crackers can easily extract apk to jar file..Then, they convert jar to java files..So, comments can see...

By the way,I tested unprotected apk...it really can see..